# Animated gif over 480 pixels wide not playing on ipad?

Tags: ipad, animated-gif

I have come across an unusual problem related to animated gifs on both the ipad and iphone on both safari and chrome and have been unable to find any posts with a similar problem.

Through a series of tests I have found that if the animated gif is over 480 pixels wide it will not play but stay on the first frame. You can view a test page here: http://www.echo3.com.au/test/animation/. They all play fine on desktop computer in all browsers.

Has anyone else had this problem as I am baffled by it?

Comment: I don't understand, how is this a software development, tools, coding, or algorithm-related problem? http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Sorry, I was not sure where to post this...

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure where to post this either. I don't think you're going to get as much help here as you would like though, because this doesn't fall in the areas of expertise the users here are expected to have. That's also probably why you haven't been able to find any posts with a similar problem. Good luck finding the solution though.

Comment: Thinking it over some more, perhaps you may have more luck on forums with iOS, iPhone, iPad, or Safari as their primary topics.